# Using an array to filter dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I would like to use the output of this ↓↓↓ dataframe column. Using the values of it, I want to filter another dataframe.

```
 X.ColumnA.unique()
array(['0', '222.33.222.106', '12.12.32.44', '122.122.1.1',
       '122.222.180.150', '142.222.180.142', '222.99.222.78',
       '33.33.221.240', '151.99.222.76', '222.251.222.1',
       '222.250.184.46', '22.33.44.55', ........ ]
```

I was using some of its values to filter and create another dataframe but I understood that I need all the values above↑↑. How can I pass the array to filter the dataframe?

```
Y = ((df['ColumnnA'] == "22.33.44.55")
| (df['ColumnnA'] == "12.12.32.44") 
| (df['ColumnnA'] == "45.142.22.22") 
| (df['ColumnnA'] == "55.197.55.8") 
| (df['ColumnnA'] == "44.44.211.254") 
| (df['ColumnnA'] == "33.44.234.83") 
| (df['ColumnnA'] == "33.33.221.240") 
| (df['ColumnnA'] == "33.33.33.1"))
restdataframe = df[~Y]
Y=df[Y]
```

Here some of the values

```
df.head(5).to_dict()
{'Column0': {0: 0.00192, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.834324, 3: 8.588816, 4: 2.908711},
 'Column1': {0: '0',
  1: '192.168.1.1',
  2: '22.22.2.15',
  3: '10.22.2.15',
  4: '10.22.22.15'},
 'ColumnA': {0: '0',
  1: '10.0.2.22',
  2: '20.55.22.22',
  3: '22.44.1.1',
  4: '44.33.1.1'},
 'Column2': {0: 'yyy', 1: 'xxx', 2: 'zzz', 3: 'xxx', 4: 'yyy'},
 'Column3': {0: '88', 1: '88', 2: '777', 3: '666', 4: '555'},
 'Column4': {0: '0', 1: '111', 2: '222', 3: '333', 4: '444'},
 'Column5': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 17, 3: 8, 4: 4},
 'Column6': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 7, 3: 4, 4: 2},
 'Column7': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 10, 3: 4, 4: 2},
 'Column8': {0: 0, 1: 110, 2: 5798, 3: 504, 4: 408},
 'Column9': {0: 0, 1: 110, 2: 775, 3: 264, 4: 188},
 'Column10': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 5023, 3: 240, 4: 220},
 'Column11': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 0},
 'Column12': {0: 'DDD', 1: 'EEE', 2: 'AAA', 3: 'BBB', 4: 'CCC'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and pass the array to filter the dataframe.

```
df[df['ColumnA'].isin(X.ColumnA.unique())]
```

Comment: I used your solution and created b=df[df.isin({'columnname': X.ColumnA.unique()})]
But when I run "b.head()", all other columns are showing "NaN", only ColumnA has some values

Comment: Can you share your dataframe as dict please. like `df.to_dict()`

Comment: okay please post `df.head(50).to_dict()`

Comment: @linuxpanther please try my updated answer and let me know what you get

Comment: I think it worked but to be sure, I would like to compare the results. I did as you suggested:
b=df[df['ColumnA'].isin(X.ColumnA.unique())]

X.ColumnA.unique() and b.ColumnA.unique() should be the same

Comment: yes should be same, if you have any trouble on that part please reply and I can check it

Comment: is there a way to compare them instead of looking at the output? (sorry, thank you so much for your help)

Comment: You mean to compare 2 dataframe or to compare 2 series?

Comment: X.ColumnA.unique() and b.ColumnA.unique() >> comparing their output

Comment: Yes you can use `np.intersect1d(t1, t2)` This will give you all common value between both the array

Comment: Thanks! They are the same.
`b=df[df['ColumnA'].isin(X.ColumnA.unique())]`

`rest = df[~b]`

`b=df[b]`

I am trying to get `b` from `df` and create two separate datasets. But getting an error `ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types`

Comment: because b is not mask dataframe, you cannot use negation on it

Comment: Did not get it, sorry. `b` is a dataframe : <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Why didn't it work? What should I change please?

Comment: What I meant was you cannot use negation operation on a non mask dataframe, mask dataframe means the one containing `True` and `False` values only.  To negate it please try this `df[~df['ColumnA'].isin(X.ColumnA.unique())]`